# How to make love2d game compatible

Tags: lua, love2d

I am getting the message "This game indicates it was made for version '0.9.1' of LOVE.
It may not be compatible with the running version (0.10.2)." when I try and run my game. The game still works but the message is annoying me. How do I update it to the latest version? My code is here:
debug = true
**Main.lua**
    -- Timers

```
-- We declare these here so we don't have to edit them multiple places
canShoot = true
canShootTimerMax = 0.2 
canShootTimer = canShootTimerMax
createEnemyTimerMax = 0.4
createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax

-- Player Object
player = { x = 200, y = 710, speed = 150, img = nil }
isAlive = true
score  = 0

-- Image Storage
bulletImg = nil
enemyImg = nil

-- Entity Storage
bullets = {} -- array of current bullets being drawn and updated
enemies = {} -- array of current enemies on screen

-- Collision detection taken function from http://love2d.org/wiki/BoundingBox.lua
-- Returns true if two boxes overlap, false if they don't
-- x1,y1 are the left-top coords of the first box, while w1,h1 are its width and height
-- x2,y2,w2 & h2 are the same, but for the second box
function CheckCollision(x1,y1,w1,h1, x2,y2,w2,h2)
  return x1 < x2+w2 and
         x2 < x1+w1 and
         y1 < y2+h2 and
         y2 < y1+h1
end

-- Loading
function love.load(arg)
    player.img = love.graphics.newImage('assets/plane.png')
    enemyImg = love.graphics.newImage('assets/enemy.png')
    bulletImg = love.graphics.newImage('assets/bullet.png')
end


-- Updating
function love.update(dt)
    -- I always start with an easy way to exit the game
    if love.keyboard.isDown('escape') then
        love.event.push('quit')
    end

    -- Time out how far apart our shots can be.
    canShootTimer = canShootTimer - (1 * dt)
    if canShootTimer < 0 then
        canShoot = true
    end

    -- Time out enemy creation
    createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimer - (1 * dt)
    if createEnemyTimer < 0 then
        createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax

        -- Create an enemy
        randomNumber = math.random(10, love.graphics.getWidth() - 10)
        newEnemy = { x = randomNumber, y = -10, img = enemyImg }
        table.insert(enemies, newEnemy)
    end


    -- update the positions of bullets
    for i, bullet in ipairs(bullets) do
        bullet.y = bullet.y - (250 * dt)

        if bullet.y < 0 then -- remove bullets when they pass off the screen
            table.remove(bullets, i)
        end
    end

    -- update the positions of enemies
    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        enemy.y = enemy.y + (200 * dt)

        if enemy.y > 850 then -- remove enemies when they pass off the screen
            table.remove(enemies, i)
        end
    end

    -- run our collision detection
    -- Since there will be fewer enemies on screen than bullets we'll loop them first
    -- Also, we need to see if the enemies hit our player
    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        for j, bullet in ipairs(bullets) do
            if CheckCollision(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.img:getWidth(), enemy.img:getHeight(), bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.img:getWidth(), bullet.img:getHeight()) then
                table.remove(bullets, j)
                table.remove(enemies, i)
                score = score + 1
            end
        end

        if CheckCollision(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.img:getWidth(), enemy.img:getHeight(), player.x, player.y, player.img:getWidth(), player.img:getHeight()) 
        and isAlive then
            table.remove(enemies, i)
            isAlive = false
        end
    end


    if love.keyboard.isDown('left','a') then
        if player.x > 0 then -- binds us to the map
            player.x = player.x - (player.speed*dt)
        end
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('right','d') then
        if player.x < (love.graphics.getWidth() - player.img:getWidth()) then
            player.x = player.x + (player.speed*dt)
        end
    end

    if love.keyboard.isDown(' ', 'rctrl', 'lctrl', 'ctrl') and canShoot then
        -- Create some bullets
        newBullet = { x = player.x + (player.img:getWidth()/2), y = player.y, img = bulletImg }
        table.insert(bullets, newBullet)
        canShoot = false
        canShootTimer = canShootTimerMax
    end

    if not isAlive and love.keyboard.isDown('r') then
        -- remove all our bullets and enemies from screen
        bullets = {}
        enemies = {}

        -- reset timers
        canShootTimer = canShootTimerMax
        createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax

        -- move player back to default position
        player.x = 50
        player.y = 710

        -- reset our game state
        score = 0
        isAlive = true
    end
end

-- Drawing
function love.draw(dt)
    for i, bullet in ipairs(bullets) do
        love.graphics.draw(bullet.img, bullet.x, bullet.y)
    end

    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        love.graphics.draw(enemy.img, enemy.x, enemy.y)
    end

    love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
    love.graphics.print("SCORE: " .. tostring(score), 400, 10)

    if isAlive then
        love.graphics.draw(player.img, player.x, player.y)
    else
        love.graphics.print("Press 'R' to restart", love.graphics:getWidth()/2-50, love.graphics:getHeight()/2-10)
    end

    if debug then
        fps = tostring(love.timer.getFPS())
        love.graphics.print("Current FPS: "..fps, 9, 10)
    end
end
```

**conf.lua**

```
-- Configuration
function love.conf(t)
    t.title = "Scrolling Shooter Tutorial" -- The title of the window the game is in (string)
    t.version = "0.9.1"         -- The LÖVE version this game was made for (string)
    t.window.width = 480        -- we want our game to be long and thin.
    t.window.height = 800

    -- For Windows debugging
    t.console = true
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to change in conf.lua variable `t.version` from "0.9.1" to "0.10.2"?

Comment: Thank you! It was a simple error but I am just starting to learn.

Comment: The reason of incompatible error could be in API changes. You can check API changes [on wiki here](https://love2d.org/wiki/0.10.2)

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, the problem in your case was that, in `conf.lua`, the version was specified as `"0.9.1"`. In some cases, changing this value to `"0.10.2"` is sufficient, but a significant amount of changes occurred between 0.9.0 and 0.10.0.

Be especially aware that mouse input is ***definitely*** going to be broken because, in versions before 0.10.0, LOVE used *strings* to represent mouse buttons, whereas in 0.10.0 and beyond, *numbers* are used. To fix this, look for mouse-related functions (`love.mouse.isDown`, `love.mousepressed`, etc.) and change `"l"` to `1`, `"r"` to `2`, and so on. See the full list of [old values](https://love2d.org/wiki/MouseConstant) and [love.mousepressed](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.mousepressed) for more. Additionally, mousewheel movement changed as well, with the addition of the [`love.wheelmoved`](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.wheelmoved) callback and removing the strings passed to `love.mousepressed`.

Additionally, read through the [changelog](https://love2d.org/wiki/0.10.0) for any changes that may have affected your program.